# Insert a tab character in PowerPoint 2016

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

I defined a tab stop in the ruler

[image]

And I would like to enter a tab character to move the cursor to the tab stop.

With older versions it was possible to enter special characters with *insert symbol* but I don't find the special characters anymore:

[image]

I also tried several key combinations as <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> without any effect.

I can I type/enter the <kbd>tab</kbd> character?

Comment: Seems solved in the latest release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a tab in a text area of a slide in **PowerPoint for Mac**, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[powerpoint](/questions/tagged/powerpoint)

Answer (score 0):

`Keynote` is accepting <kbd>tab</kbd> directly. Is much easier to use than any version of `PowerPoint` and is able to output `PowerPoint` format which is readable with many `PowerPoint` versions.

My personnal experience is that `Keynote` is providing a more compatible `PowerPoint` than any version of `PowerPoint`, and is also much user friendly.

Actually I don't use `PowerPoint` for quality and security reasons.

Then this part of advice is *untested*!

I suggest you to try:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd>

or:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd>